# CSS animación vs transición

Tags: html, css, css3, animación

Tengo bien claro que `animation` y `transition` son para realizar animaciones, pero...

Supongamos que quiero mover un elemento de izquierda a derecha, con ambas se puede hacer.

Ejemplo con `animation`:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = e => {
  document.getElementById('img').classList.add('move');
}
```

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: 200px; }
}
.move {
  animation: move 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://a.imge.to/2019/08/11/fjHnk.th.jpg"/><br/>
<button id="button">Mover</button>
```

Ejemplo con `transition`:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = e => {
  document.getElementById('img').classList.add('move');
}
```

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 2s;
}
#img.move {
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://a.imge.to/2019/08/11/fjHnk.th.jpg"/><br/>
<button id="button">Mover</button>
```

---

- ¿En algún momento conviene usar una o la otra?
- ¿Qué ventaja que tiene una sobre la otra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Animaciones CSS**

Una animación contiene las siguientes [propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

- `animation-name`
- `animation-duration`
- `animation-timing-function`
- `animation-delay`
- `animation-iteration-count`
- `animation-direction`
- `animation-fill-mode`
- `animation-play-state`

Entonces observamos lo siguiente:

> Una animación aplicada a un elemento o un grupo de elementos puede no solo contener: dirección, tiempo y frecuencia.

Por ejemplo en el siguiente fragmento animamos con un giro infinito a la figura que se encuentra por dentro del círculo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Animación</title>
      <style>
        #circulomayor{
          width: 150px;
          height:150px;
          background-color: crimson;
          border-radius: 50%;
          position: relative;
        }
        #circulomenor{
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: tomato;
          border-radius: 50px 100px 20px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 35px;
          left: 45px;
          animation: girar 2s linear infinite;
        }
        
        @keyframes girar{
          from{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          to{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="circulomayor">
      <div id="circulomenor"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Entonces una animación nos permite establecer comportamiento complejo e iterable de distintos elementos en la pantalla.

> Las animaciones de diferencia de las transiciones poseen su paso de un estado inicial a un estado final con un intermedio entre ellas a través de [fotogramas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotograma) los cuales ayudan a indicar comportamientos específicos entre el inicio y el fin de ambos estados.

Por eso para establecer el comportamiento de todos los `fotogramas` poseemos una regla llamada [`keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) en la cual por dentro podemos indicar el comportamiento que cada paso de la *animación* tendrá:

Por ejemplo:

```
@keyframes mianimacion {
   from{
     //estado inicial
   }
   to{
     //estado final
   }
}
```

Incluso que se disparen por la interacción de un usuario, por ejemplo que la animación anterior ocurra cuando el usuario haga `:hover` sobre el elemento del `DOM`.

```
#circulomenor:hover{
  animation: girar 2s linear infinite;
}
```

**Transiciones CSS**

Las transiciones en [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition), poseen las siguientes propiedades:

- `transition-duration`
- `transition-timing-function`
- `transition-delay`
- `transition-property`

Donde estas solo nos permiten tener 2 estados, uno **inicial** y uno **final** sin efectos de animación intermedia.

Para el ejemplo anterior, lo que obtendríamos sería algo similar a esto:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Otro mas</title>
      <style>
        #circulomayor{
          width: 150px;
          height:150px;
          background-color: crimson;
          border-radius: 50%;
          position: relative;
        }
        #circulomenor{
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: tomato;
          border-radius: 50px 100px 20px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 35px;
          left: 45px;
        }
        #circulomenor:hover{
          background-color: green;
          transition: background-color 3s ease-in;
        }
    
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="circulomayor">
      <div id="circulomenor"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Donde cambiamos el color de fondo por medio de la propiedad `transition` indicando la propiedad afectada, la duración de la transición y la regularidad con la cual se visualizará.

Entonces podemos identificar que:

- Las animaciones permiten generar comportamientos intermedios entre el estado inicial y final de la misma, con ayuda de los keyframes que generan *fotogramas*
- La cantidad de propiedades para aplicar efectos en una transición son menores en comparación con una animación.
- Probablemente para igualar una transición a nivel de *keyframes* con respecto de una animación deberemos aplicar el uso de *JavaScript*
- Puedes elegir usar transiciones cuando no requieras de puntos intermedios específicos de animación a los elementos y en cambio solo sea mostrar un estado incial y final